# Antiderivative of the Jacobian of a vector function on a line

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Let $f\colon \R^m\to\R^n$ be differentiable and $a,b\in\R^m$. Denote the Jacobian of $f$ as $g\colon \R^m \to \R^{n\times m}$. Consider the integral
$$\int_0^1 g(a+\theta b)\,d\theta.$$
Is there a way to construct an antiderivative $G\colon [0,1]\to \R^{n\times m}$ of the function $\theta\mapsto g(a+\theta b)$ such that
$$\int_0^1 g(a+\theta b)\,d\theta = G(1) - G(0)?$$
Can $G$ be expressed in terms of $f$?

Comment: Have you tried a simple example?

Comment: Yes, I did some smaller examples, where I could calculate the antiderivative explicitly in terms of $\theta$, but I could not figure out how it can be written using $f$.